# how to make a phone call from android adapter recyclerview using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm new to Kotlin and am trying to make phone call from a recycler view that has the button for the phone number, I want when i click on the button it should open up my phone dialer with the number automatically however when i click on the button, nothing happens.

here is what i've done:

I gave the permission for making a call in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
```

my recyclerview has the image, name, contact, the expertise and the button for calling the contact

[image: here is an image of the recyclweview]

here is my code snippet for the adapter that is supposed to carry out the activity. Im not sure, but maybe there could be a problem with my method.

```
    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.net.Uri
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
    
    class ConsultantAdapter(private val modelList: List<ConsultantModel>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ConsultantAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    
        private lateinit var callBtnListener: View.OnClickListener 
  classConsultantAdapter(valmodelList:List<ConsultantModel>,callBtnListener:View.OnClickListener) {}
    
        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            private val cImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image)
            private val cName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.consultant_name)
            private val cContact: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.consultant_contact)
            private val cExpertise: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.consultant_expertise)
    
            val callBtn: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_consultant_button)
    
            fun setEvents(resource: String, name: String, contact: String, expertise: String) {
                Glide.with(itemView.context).load(resource).into(cImage)
                cName.text = name
                cContact.text = contact
                cExpertise.text = expertise
    
                itemView.setOnClickListener{
                    val intent: Intent = Uri.parse(contact).let { number ->
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number)
                    }
                    itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val galleryView =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.consultants_item, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(galleryView)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val resource = modelList[position].image
            val name = modelList[position].name
            val contact = modelList[position].contact
            val expertise = modelList[position].expertise
            holder.setEvents(resource, name, contact, expertise)
            
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return modelList.size
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
setOnClickListener
```

to either your callBtn, or make a reference to your parent view like Relative Layout or whatever you have used to wrap all children views.

The ItemView here, is perhaps a root view for the layout, row or cell and you can bind it to any view using

> as